# Using D3 in React without svg for table rows arn't rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am looking to take a current working d3 table, and implement the table as a react component.  Almost all the D3 examples use svg, while I am not using this tag.

I'm able to get the JSON data outputting to the console, but it is not appending the rows.

Here is my original D3.html page.

```
var column_names = ["Select","Deploy ID", "Requestor", "Market", "Env","Group","Deploy Date", "Approver", "Completed Date", "CRQ", "Job Status"];


// draw the table
d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "container")

d3.select("#container").append("div")
    .attr("id", "FilterableTable");


var table = d3.select("#FilterableTable").append("table");
table.append("thead").append("tr");





var headers = table.select("tr").selectAll("th")
    .data(column_names)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

var filterButton = d3.select("#filterButton");


var rows;

d3.json("data.json", function(data) { // loading data from server

    // draw table body with rows
    table.append("tbody")

    // data bind
    rows = table.select("tbody").selectAll("tr")
        .data(data, function(d){ return d.deploy_id; });

    // enter the rows
    rows.enter()
        .append("tr")
        .append("td") .append("input") .attr("type", "checkbox")

    // enter td's in each row
    row_entries = rows.selectAll("td")

        .data(function(d) {
            var arr = [];
            for (var k in d) {
                if (d.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    arr.push(d[k]);
                }
            }
            return [arr[0],arr[0],arr[11],arr[9],arr[7],arr[5],arr[4],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[8]];

        })


        .enter()
        .append("td")


    row_entries.text(function(d) { return d; })

 });
```

Here is how far I've gotten with D3 and react, I've changed the d3.json method, and I'm able to get the data.json values to log by keeping the data.json in the /public folder, but I am unable to build the rows with the values from data.json

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";

class ViewDeploys extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.drawTable();
}

drawTable() {

    var column_names = ["Select","Deploy ID", "Requestor", "Market", "Env","Group","Deploy Date", "Approver", "Completed Date", "CRQ", "Job Status"];


    // draw the table
    d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("id", "container")

    d3.select("#container").append("div")
        .attr("id", "FilterableTable");


    var table = d3.select("#FilterableTable").append("table");
    table.append("thead").append("tr");





    var headers = table.select("tr").selectAll("th")
        .data(column_names)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

    var filterButton = d3.select("#filterButton");


    var rows;

   // d3.json("/data.json", function(data) { // loading data from server
        d3.json("/data.json").then((data) => {
            // draw table body with rows
        table.append("tbody")

        // data bind
        rows = table.select("tbody").selectAll("tr")
            .data(data, function(d){ return d.deploy_id; });

        // enter the rows
        rows.enter()
            .append("tr")
            .append("td") .append("input") .attr("type", "checkbox")

        // enter td's in each row
        var row_entries = rows.selectAll("td")

            .data(function(d) {
                var arr = [];
                for (var k in d) {
                    if (d.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                        arr.push(d[k]);
                    }
                }
                return [arr[0],arr[0],arr[11],arr[9],arr[7],arr[5],arr[4],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[8]];

            })


            .enter()
            .append("td")


        row_entries.text(function(d) { return d; })

    });





}


render() {
    const id = '1';
    return (
        <section className="viewDeploysContainer">
            <svg id={id} />
        </section>
    );
}
}

export default ViewDeploys;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to draw table without actually react render and this is wrong, react will call render method and your table will go away.
My propose to use any solution with already integrated react with d3, here are some example libs:
https://github.com/nteract/semiotic
http://recharts.org/en-US/guide/getting-started

Comment: I'm able to get some part of it rendering, so the table is there, it is just not filling the rows in.  I'll add a screenshot.